# Ran Mongo queries in repo interface in spring boot app the query is not giving any error but the output is null

Tags: java, spring-boot, mongodb-query, repository

I want to update some rows in my mongo document based on some criteria

```
    @Query("{'ao.status': ?0, 'ao.otp_type': ?1}")
    void updateOtpStatus(String otpStatus, String otpType);
    
    @Query(value="{'status': ?0, 'otp_type': ?1,'user_id':?2}")
    AuthOtpModel getActivOtp(String userId, String otpStatus, String otpType);
    
    @Query(value = "{otp:?0,status:?1,otp_type:?2}")
    Date getOtpCreatedAt(String ActiveOtp, String otpStatus, String otpType);
```

these are the queries or code that i have tried